# VIM putting a line at the top (or bottom) of a tile to set attributes? doesnt work for me

Tags: vim, text-formatting

I read in "Vim book OPL.pdf" that you can put a line at the top of a file, say for instance a .txt file and it would change how that individual file was handled by Vim. for example
vim:tw=78

however it doesnt do anything for me and I am wondering if this is still the case for vim7.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a "modeline" and you can get more information by typing:
`:help modeline`

From the description in help, I think the correct format should be `vim: tw=78`

It seems your example is missing white spaces.

Addition from elwoode comment :
Adding the modeline won't reformat automatically existing text. If you want to reformat you have to select an area and use `gq`. See `:help gq`

To reformat the whole file according to modeline, use:
`gggqG` (`gg` means go to first line, `gq`apply formating to motion, `G`go to last line)

Be sure that in .vimrc you have `formatoptions+=t` to take into account formatting according to textwidth. It seems that on my installation `t` is part of the default `formatoptions`.

Comment: I've tried   vim:tw=60  vim: tw=60  :set tw=60 :set textwidth=60

Comment: Have you left a whitespace before `vim` ? I have just tried on an existing text file, it works with vim 7.3. However, it does not format existing text, it only go automatically to next line after textwidth characters.

Comment: THAT's IT !!!   I thought if you put a formatting command on a file it would change the text to that format next time you opened it. Thanks to you I know if only changes new stuff you type into that file.  So it was working all the time. So basically you have to remember to do this first before typing stuff in.

Comment: However you can reformat existing text by selecting an area and using `gq`. see `:help gq`. Potentially you have to set the right `formatoptions' to get `gq`working.

Answer (score 3):

The modeline is often disabled by default due to security reasons (the last of which are abolished in Vim 7.3 as I understand it); it is in Debian, for example. It will be in your case (see `:set modeline?`).

Add `set modeline` to your vimrc if you wish to enable modeline support.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6).

Syntax would be:

```
vim:set textwidth=78:
```

Comment: also, you will need to turn on the modeline option; :set modeline, and indicate how many modelines to try to read; :set modelines=1

Comment: I had :set modeline already set but have now tried :set modelines=1  still not working. I notice if I open a file (like one of the help txt files that have the same command as I have been trying vim:tw=72 it is working but not if I try to do that in a file I make

Answer (score 0):

Just an option, you can use your .vimrc if you want:

```
autocmd FileType .txt set textwidth=78
```